# FuelSDK for Node.js is using Sync API or Async?

Tags: fuel-sdk

We need to push data into SFMC from external system and we are using Node.js FuelSDK for the same. 
Here is a URL,
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST

As data volume is huge we are planning to use Async APIs rather than Sync but we are not sure FuelSDK is using Sync or Async calls.

How can we confirm the same?

Please assist.

Thanks,